# Print without evaluating

Tags: hold

I want to print, for example `Print[a + b]`, but
first

```
a = RandomChoice[{-3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3}];
b = RandomChoice[{-3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3}];
```

And every time you calculate the random value, I can see
`2  +  3` or `-3 + 1`  without evaluating.

Comment: If you have a longer list of numbers, say `{a1, a2, ..., an}`, then you could do `StringRiffle[ToString /@ {a1, a2, ..., an}, "+"]`. One possible problem is that you'll get things like `2 + -3` if you don't select `+` or `-` based on the sign.

Answer (score 4):

It is hard to explain the details without explaining the whole Mathematica evaluation chain. There are many ways to achieve this. If you just want to "see" the sum, then you can start by evaluating the line

```
Dynamic[a] + Dynamic[b]
```

after that, you can evaluate as often as you want

```
a = RandomChoice[{-3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3}];
b = RandomChoice[{-3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3}];
```

and see the update. Note that you want to use `Defer` if you try something like

```
Defer[Dynamic[a] + Dynamic[a]]
```

If you really want to print it, then Nassers advice works as well. Or you can use `Inactivate`

```
a = RandomChoice[{-3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3}];
b = RandomChoice[{-3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3}];
Inactivate[a + b]
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Inactive`, `HoldForm`, `Defer` ...

```
{a, b} = RandomChoice[{-3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3}, 2]; 
Defer[#+#2]&[a,b]
HoldForm[#+#2]&[a,b]
Inactive[Plus][a,b]
With[{a = a, b = b}, HoldForm[a + b]]
With[{a = a, b = b}, Defer[a + b]]
```

all give

> -2 + 3